# Preventing scripted POST in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my ASP.NET MVC project, user can save a form on screen which makes HTTP POST request to server.

How can I prevent client to send automated HTTP POST's to server. Is there any builtin way on IIS or web.config to block unusal request rates?

For example a setting like, "based on Session ID, request count in 1 minute cannot exceed 30" could be helpful.

Captcha control is not a good option for me. Because there are many save options on screen, setting captcha for each of them will be useless.

Comment: One option would be [Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked for, but you can use session variables to limit a form from being posted unless the form is first requested, and protect against being submitted multiple times.

On your form page, generate a random number:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int key = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
```

Create a session variable with this number as the name, something like this:

```
Session["key_"+ key.ToString()] = true;
```

In your form add a hidden field with this number:

```
<input name="key" type="hidden" value="@key" />
```

Upon form post get the hidden field value and check that the session variable exists. Then remove the session variable so the form cannot be resubmitted:

```
int key = 0;
int.TryParse(Request.Form["key"] ?? string.Empty, out key);

if (Session["key_" + key.ToString()] == null)
{
    //invalid post, take some action
    //best to return the user to the form and give them another chance
    //in case it was legitimate, eg. session timed out 
}
else
{
    Session.Contents.Remove("key_" + key.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mvc attribute called AntiForgeryToken on your post action method, It generates a encrypted value and a salt used to verify if your post is authentic.

See this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx